# Automatic change values, in instance of class, by event

Tags: matlab, events, listener, class-design

I would like to create a class that (for simplicity) adds two numbers as soon as I change an input parameter in an instance of the class. For simplicity I have created this class:

```
classdef test < handle
    properties (Constant)
        privatNummer = 10;
    end

    properties
        brugerNummer;
        sum;
    end

    methods
        function obj = test()
            obj.sum = method1(obj);
        end

        function obj = method1(obj)
            obj.sum = obj.brugerNummer + obj.privatNummer;
        end
    end
end
```

How do I get it to automatically update obj.sum when I give it a new value? Currently I have to run obj.method1 every time I want to update obj.sum.

I have tried something like this (but I just can't get it working):

```
classdef test < handle
    properties (Constant)
        privatNummer = 10;
    end

    properties
        brugerNummer;
        sum;
    end

    methods
        function obj = test()
            notify(obj,'StateChange')
            obj.sum = method1(obj);
            addlistener(obj.brugerNummer,'Ændret nummer',@RespondToToggle.method1);
        end

        function src = method1(src)
            src.sum = src.brugerNummer + src.privatNummer; 
        end
    end
    events
        StateChange
    end
end
```

Comment: How do you intend to give a new number? This is not clear to me. When you give a new number, you must call a function. This function can update the other number too. You might want to look into property setters, which are functions called when you do `obj.sum=2`. You might also want to investigate dependent properties, which is what you’re trying to implement.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo. I'd create a script where I create an instance of the class: `a = test;` and then I would change `a.brugerNummer = 10`. And I would like the `a.sum` to be calculated every time I change the `brugerNummer` automatically. This is a fairly simplified example. I'm trying to write a class that calculates the sound of speed in any given medium depending on what parameters one has (temperature, density, adiabatic bulk module, etc.). I've been using Matlab for yeats, but oop is new to me. Anyway, thanks for your help! I'll defenitly look into property setters and dependent properties.

Comment: *speed of sound... (:

Comment: @bgaard as @CrisLuengo mentions, you could implement a [Dependent Property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html) for the `sum` property. Another option could be to use a `PostSet` event listener. Briefly, you'd set the property access for the `brugerNumer` to `SetObservable=true` and then you would add an event listener, `addlistener(obj, "brugerNumer", "PostSet", @callbackFcn)` and then define the callback function (`function callbackFcs(obj, source,event)...`) to do your required calculations and modifications of other properties.

Comment: You can do as @Khlick suggests with the event listener, or you can simply define a method `obj = set.brugerNummer(obj,value)` that is invoked whenever the value is assigned to.

Comment: Thanks guys! CrisLuengo's solution was very easy to implement. Khlick, I spent three hours reading forums and matlab help-sites to get the syntax down, but i really like the solution. It is, however, not very intuitive and it seems like the method is usually used for broadcasting messages, rather than changing values though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed two solutions for the problems. The first relying on `Dependent` `properties`, setters and getters; the second relying on listeners and callback-functions.

First Solution:

```
classdef test
    properties (Constant)
        privatNummer = 10;
    end

    properties
        brugerNummer;
    end
    properties (Dependent)
        sum;
    end

    methods   
        function obj = test()
            % Constructor
        end     

        function value = get.sum(obj)
            value = obj.brugerNummer + obj.privatNummer;
        end
    end
end
```

Second Solution (this was a real hassle):

```
classdef test < handle
    properties (Constant)
        privatNummer = 10;
    end

    properties (SetObservable)
        brugerNumber;
    end
    properties
        sum;
    end

    methods
        function obj = test()
            % constructor
            addlistener(obj, 'brugerNumber', 'PostSet',@test.callbackFun);
        end

    end

    methods (Static)
        function callbackFun(~,evnt)
            obj = evnt.AffectedObject;
            obj.sum = obj.brugerNumber + obj.privatNummer;
        end     
    end
end
```

Comment: Great solution @bgaard. I suggested an edit. The static method is not required for the PostSet callback. You can simply call another method (public or otherwise) and deal with the expected `source` and `event` inputs (`doSum(obj,source,event)...`). Still, dependent method is the best option in my opinion.